# Константа static + final, или только final?

Tags: java, static, final

Чтобы создать константу в Java, нужно пометить переменную сразу двумя модификаторами: static и final. Прочитал это в книге, а если просто переменную final помечаю, тогда у меня что не константа получается?

Comment: Константа, Но в каждом созданном объекте своя

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`final` достаточно для создания константы. `static` используется для того, чтобы хранить константу в памяти один раз, а не столько раз, сколько создано экземпляров класса (см. выши предыдущие вопросы).

Answer (score 2):

Ключевое слово - `final` заставляет вас проинициализировать переменную сразу же, или в конструкторе, так же для переменных примитивного типа это означает, что однажды присвоенное значение не может быть изменено, и да, ключевое слово `final` определяет константу, ивозможно у Вас появится вопрос как `final` работает не с примитивами, так вот, `final` запрещает переопределять метод, и наследоваться от класса. При использовании `final` на ссылочном типе данных константой является ссылка, а не сам объект. Неизменяемость или `Immutable` объекта достигается за счет удаление методов модификации данных.